# Spring list beans by type

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Is there a way in Spring that I can auto populate a list with all of beans of a type AND any of its subtypes? I have a setter method that looks like:

```
setMyProp(List<MyType> list)
```

And I would like to autowire in any beans of MyType and all subclasses of MyType.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: How do you want this list to work with prototypes? Should it contain just one instance, have each instance added (memory leak) or be back by some form of weak reference list.

Comment: all the beans will be singletons in my case

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yup, you can do this. The spring docs say:

> It is also possible to provide all
>   beans of a particular type from the
>   ApplicationContext by adding the
>   annotation to a field or method that
>   expects an array of that type.

Note that it says you need to expect an array, not a list. This makes sense, because generic type erasure means a list may not work at runtime. However, take the following unit test, which works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">  

    <bean class="test.Test.TypeB"/>
    <bean class="test.Test.TypeC"/>
    <bean class="test.Test.TypeD"/>
</beans>
```

and this unit test:

```
package test;

@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Test {

    private @Autowired List<TypeA> beans;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(beans);
        assertEquals(2, beans.size());
        for (TypeA bean : beans) {
            assertTrue(bean instanceof TypeA);
        }
    }       

    public static interface TypeA {}
    public static class TypeB implements TypeA {}
    public static class TypeC extends TypeB {}
    public static class TypeD {}

}
```

So officially, you're supposed to autowire `TypeA[]`, not `List<TypeA>`, but the List works good.

Answer (score 5):

If it's acceptable to fill the list from your application code and not from within the bean definition file you could use the `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory` and ask it "`getBeansOfType( MyType.class )`". This gives you all beans of type (and subtype) of `MyType`.

Comment: This actually works for all classes implementing ListableBeanFactory ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType%28java.lang.Class%29 )

Answer (score 3):

If you can use  `@Autowired` inside the code to be populated you can safely use the way mentioned by skaffman. If you insist on XML configuration there is a small library called [Hera](http://hera.synyx.org) to achieve this. Esentially configuration of a scenario described by you looks like this:

```
<bean id="client" class="..">
    <property name="injectDynamicListHere">
        <hera:list class="my.custom.SuperType" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

This will inject all top-level Spring beans implementing `SuperType` as `List` into the client bean.

Comment: cool, thanks. I was able to use the @Autowired in the code, but this is good to know.

Comment: Perhaps one minor thing to add is that the Hera list respects @Ordered annotations resp. implementing Ordered interface to allow determining order of the beans injected.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Java generics work by type erasure, meaning that at runtime that parameter is simply a List, not a List of a generic type. As such you can't figure out that it is meant to be of parameter type MyType so it wouldn't be possible to implement this behaviour.

That being said, there are alternative ways of doing this. The most obvious seems to be to listen for bean creation and then seeing if they are of MyType (or subclasses) and then keeping a reference.

There is probably a few ways to do this. One is [creating a bean post-processor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension). This way you'll get notified of every bean that's created.

Comment: Type information for method parameters is not completely erased and still available to the runtime. You can access this via the Method or Constructor getGenericParameterTypes method.

Comment: @mik: yes but he was talking about a parameter on a function where no such information is available.

Answer (score 0):

Due to legacy code and missing @Autowired I solve it like:

```
MyBean implements ApplicationContextAware{

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
    final Map<String, HttpRequestHandlerTemplate> beansOfType = ctx.getBeansOfType(RequiredBean.class);
    ...
}
```