# spring component scan for classes

Tags: spring

I want to scan all the classes in a package that that are subclasses of the particular class.
Then I want to take these classes and for each of them instantiate a bean of same type, using the class as a property.
Then I want to gather all these anonymous beans and put them into collection. Is it possible to configure spring context in XML like this?
Thx

Answer (score 2):

Just use this class:

[ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html)

```
method: findCandidateComponents.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't list all classes that are contained in a package without direct access to the location where the class files are stored (usually the filesystem).

For the second part of your question have a look at [spring-list-beans-by-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450145/spring-list-beans-by-type).

Comment: Spring's component-scan does just this (scans all classes under some package and checks them for specific properties), so this seems to be possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that sounds like what you're asking for is the `<context:component-scan>` pattern (see docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations)), but what you're asking for is highly specific, and to be honest, doesn't make much sense. If you could give a concrete example, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way for you to implement this would be to write your own implementation of the Spring FactoryBean interface, and do all the introspection / reflection and scanning in that implementation to generate the end bean that you want put in the Spring applicationContext.