# Inject a list of classes that extends an abstract class with Spring

Tags: spring, list, inject

Hy,

I have the next code:

```
public abstract class MyClass{
   protected abstract void method1();
}
```

Classes that extend the first one:

```
 @Component
 public class MyClass1 extends MyClass{
    .....
 }

@Component
public class MyClass2 extends MyClass{
  .....
}
```

My class where I try to inject list of classes that extends an abstract class

```
 @Component
 public class SpringClass{

     @Autowired **//It doesnt work, nothing is inyected!**
     List<MyClass> classes

 }
```

My problem is it doesnt work, it doesnt inject the list of classes that extend MyClass in property classes. Why?

Thanks

Comment: It should work for Spring 3.1+, I think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450145/spring-list-beans-by-type Does the injection work for the normal case(just inject MyClass1 for example) and not for a list?

Comment: Are you sure your components are scanned?

Comment: Yes, my components are scanned but when I use an interface the list is inyected, when I use an abstract class no; it doesnt matter if I try to inject a list or a single element, it doesnt work with an abstract class

Answer (score 0):

You can remove @Autowired annotation for the instance variable and add it to the setter method. After doing this your spring class would be

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringClass {

    List<MyClass> classes;

    @Autowired
    public void setClasses(List<MyClass> classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't matter (where @Autowired will be located), source from the question works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class SpringClass {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, YourInterface> map;

}
```

String in map will be contain all classes name that implements the YourInterface as String.
if you want to get all instances - use map.values()
if you want to get specific instance - get it by class name.

in additional, you can customize the key by another recognize such as Enum.
in this case - you need to configure this as @Bean
as bellow :

```
@Configuration
public class CalculationHandlerConfig {

    @Bean
    public HashMap<OperatorTypeEnum, CalculatorService> CalculationHandlers(Map<String, CalculatorService> beansMap) {
        HashMap<OperatorTypeEnum, CalculatorService> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (CalculatorService bean : beansMap.values()) {
            map.put(bean.getOperatorType(), bean);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be dependent on the version of Spring being used, however, you may also want to try using an interface that all the desired classes implement, and injecting the list referencing the interface.

In other words, instead of this..

`List<AbstractOrConcreteBaseClass>`

use...

`List<Interface>`